# Does anyone know how to make an embedded spotify playlist responsive?

Tags: spotify

Looking to have a spotify playlist a certain size when viewing on desktop, but smaller on mobile?  The code is HTML

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please refer to [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a responsive Spotify embedded iframe, but only to an extent. Spotify limits a user: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/widgets/spotify-play-button/

There is a min and max width (height x width):

- max: 720px x 640px
- min: 80px x 250px

If you are using media queries, these dimensions should work on mobile and desktop.